# How can I keep a package but discard its configuration?

Tags: apt

I know I can use this to remove a package but keep configuration:

```
sudo apt-get remove $package
```

I know I can also use this to remove a package and discard its configuration files:

```
sudo apt-get purge $package
```

But what if I want to keep a package but discard its configuration?

<sup>**Context:** I did something wrong with Network Manager and it's started segfaulting on a loop, and while `sudo service network-manager stop` works, I also kinda want to use WiFi. If this was just any old boring package, I could just purge and reinstall it. That's obviously not an option for Network Manager, since ubuntu-desktop depends on it.</sup>

Comment: Is this what `sudo apt-get install --reinstall $package` does?

Comment: Which configuration do you mean? The configuration, e.g. in `/etc` or in your home folder? I believe you mean the configuration in your home folder. I'm right?

Comment: @A.B. I don't know where NM stores its configuration to be entirely honest with you, but I know that `install --reinstall` was sufficient to stop the desperate segfaulting, at least until I tried to reconnect with the offending WiFi network again.

Comment: Yes, therefore `install --reinstall` in my answer. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reinstall the package and overwrite the changed configurations in `/etc` with the configuration of the package run

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" install --reinstall package_name
```

But this command doesn't affect configurations in your home folder, because nothing in the home folder will be changed by the package manager.